# Flutter Firebase package... Streambuilder "snapshot.data.documents" error

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

[`snapshot.data.documents`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLHRE.png)

[`dependency = firebase:core`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6mLU.png)

I want to fix this error.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the newer version of `cloud_firestore`, which is good.
But you are using older API syntax. To access the documents in your query, you should use:

```
snapshot.data.docs // instead of 'documents'
```